# running a C application on freertos ,which is already running on uclinux

Tags: freertos, cortex-m, uclinux

an application is running on uclinux which is installed on cortex-m3,
but now i want to use freertos as Os instead of uclinux,

For e.g. I run a tcp server client application where client is on uclinux and server is on computer with linux installed ,it works well and vice versa also works

In case of FreeRTOS,I am using lwip as ip stack ,the application and freertos and lwip gets compiled and the hex file is generated and i can put it into cortex-m3 but when i run it there is no communication between server and client

--->So are there any specific changes i need to make

used arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc toolchain for uclinux
used arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain for freertos

Answer (score 0):

That is a massively open question that can only possibly be answered by asking many questions back to you, so I will instead just offer advise.

First I would suggest cutting the problem down into manageable pieces.  Start by ensuring you can execute FreeRTOS on your part (there are lots of [Cortex-M examples](http://www.freertos.org/RTOS_ports.html), and even [TCP examples for Cortex-M](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/TCP_FAT_demo_projects.html), and an FAQ to look through if you have problems getting the RTOS running, all available on the FreeRTOS.org web site).

Second, in a bare metal application (without an RTOS or OS), check the lwIP driver is able to send and receive on the Ethernet port.

Third add the known working Ethernet driver into your known working FreeRTOS project, and check the Ethernet driver is still working (taking note of the FAQ items on the FreeRTOS website with regards to having stack overflow checking on, configASSERT() defined, etc.).

Fourth stitch in the lwIP code, noting the lwIP recommendations for using the stack in a multi-threaded application.

Fifth etc. etc.